# overloading Extraction and Insertion << >> operator c++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to overload the << (cout)  and >> (cin) operators for awhile now for a class of complex numbers that I was given the prototypes for in a .h file to do.

This is my attempt to do so in the class.cpp file:

```
std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, complex& c) {
    double h, j;
    in >> h >> j;

    c.set(h,j);

    return in;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, complex c) {
    out << c.getReal;
    out << c.getImag;

    return out;
}
```

1. This is really the first time I've seen the `std:: istream` and `std:: ostream` rather than cout and cin and i'm not really sure how `cout <<`  and  `cin >>` are all related
2. I try testing it on the main.cpp file but i get errors
3. The `>>` should absorb a complex argument into the complex class argument and change the value of private members `real` and `imag`
4. Not sure if I'm supposed to use my set function here

This is the protype .h file filled I was given:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H


class complex {

public:
    complex();
    complex(double a);
    complex(double a, double b);
    complex(int a, int b);
    void print() const;
    void set(double a = 0, double b = 0);
    void set(int a = 0, int b = 0);
    double getReal() const;
    double getImag() const;
    void get(double&, double&) const;

    complex operator+ (double& x);
    complex operator+ (complex&);
    complex operator+= (complex&);
    complex operator+= (int&);
    complex operator++ (int);
    complex operator++ ();
    complex operator- (double&);
    complex operator- (complex&);
    complex operator-= (complex&);
    complex operator-= (double&);
    complex operator-- (int);
    complex operator-- ();
    complex operator* (complex&);
    complex operator* (double&);
    complex operator*= (complex&);
    complex operator*= (double&);
    complex operator/ (complex&);
    complex operator/= (complex&);
    complex operator/= (double);
    complex operator/ (double);
    void operator= (const complex&);
    bool operator== (complex&);
    bool operator!=(complex &c);

    friend std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, complex& c);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, complex c);

    /*complex conj() const;
    double norm() const;
    double modulus() const;
    */
private:
    double real;
    double imag;
};

#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

Can someone show me how to properly overload for this?

Ok so I'm now trying for output a + bi :

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, complex const& c) {
    return out << c.getReal() << "+" << c.getImag() << "i";
}
```

and for input:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, complex& c) {
    double h, j;
    if (in >> h >> "+" >> j >> "i") {
        c.set(h, j);
    }
    return in;
}
```

However I get the following error when I compile:

This is for line 181 of my complex.cpp file(class complex implementation file) where `if (in >> h >> "+" >> j >> "i") {`is located of the above function definition is located:

```
binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [2]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

the following are all for line 45(Note each error is separate,total of 7 for this line) of my complex.h file where `friend std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, complex& c);` protoype is located.

```
'istream':is not a member of 'std'

syntax error missing ';' before '&'

'istream':'friend' not permitted on data declarations

missing type specifier-int assumed. Note:C++ does not support default-int

unexpected token(s) preceding';'


namespace "std" has no member "istream"

namespace "std" has no member "istream"
```

the following are for line 46 of my complex.h file where

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, complex c);
```

is located

```
'ostream': is not a member of 'std'

syntax error: missing ';' before '&'

'ostream':'friend' not permitted on data declarations

missing type specifier -int assumed.Note: C++ does not support default-int

unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

namespace "std" has no member "ostream"

namespace "std" has no member "ostream"
```

I noticed both are the same type of errors. Note I have

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
```

both on the complex.cpp file and the main.cpp file

Comment: Seems reasonable, except you need to call the `get` functions, not just name them. Change `getReal` to `getReal()`, and similarly `getImag` to `getImag()` in `operator<<`. Also, have you thought about separating the output parts? Say, with a comma. Other than that, you may be better asking this over at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: In what way does the code not work? ... and I will tell off @BoBTFish for claiming it is reasonable despite the input function not checking its inputs before using!

Comment: You need to make your functions [`const` correct](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness).

Comment: @DietmarKühl Well I was trying not to get too involved in a comment when this should be on a different SE anyway, but you are right of course. (You wouldn't know since I usually don't use my real name online, but you can tell me off in person just by looking right.)

Comment: "I get errors" is not a helpful piece of information.

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with the simple stuff: `std::cin` is an instance of a type derived from `std::istream`. Similarly, `std::cout` is an instance of a type derived from `std::ostream`. These stream types are used to have something you can overload the input and output operators for (and you should *not* try to derive from them to change their behavior - that's done using `std::streambuf`). There are other stream types, e.g., `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream` (to read from/write to files) and `std::istringstream`/`std::ostringstream` (to read from/write to strings).

The next thing to look at is your output operator: for starters, you need parenthesis when calling a member function. You'll also need a separator between the two values as otherwise the real and the imaginary part may blend into each other. I'd probably implement the operator as

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, complex const& value) {
    return out << value.getReal() << " " << value.getImag();
}
```

The use of a space and no other delimiter may be suboptimal in general but makes reading easier. For an actual implementation of a complex class I might use a format writing *real*`+`*imag*`i` or `(`*real*`,`*imag*`)` but these are harder to parse.

Reading values from a stream should *always* be checked after an attempt to read a value was made. For example, the code could look like this:

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& in, complex& c) {
    double h, j;
    if (in >> h >> j) {
        c.set(h, j);
    }
    return in;
}
```

Except for the missing check the input function looks OK assuming the two values are separated by a space: before attempting to read a value, space is skipped by default with the input operators. If the values are formatted more fancy with some separators, these would need to be separately processed. The code to do so could look like the this:

```
template <char C>
std::istream& skip_char(std::istream& in) {
    if ((in >> std::skipws).peek() != C) {
        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    else {
        in.ignore();
    }
    return in;
}
std::istream& (*const open_parenthesis)(std::istream&) = &skip_char<'('>;
std::istream& (*const close_parenthesis)(std::istream&) = &skip_char<')'>;
std::istream& (*const comma)(std::istream&) = &skip_char<','>;

std::istream& operator<< (std::istream& in, complex& c) {
    double real, imag;
    if (in >> open_parenthesis >> real >> comma >> imag >> close_parenthesis) {
        c.set(real, imag);
    }
    return in;
}
```

These funny looking entities `open_parenthesis`, `close_parenthesis`, and `comma` are function pointers initialized to point to instance of the function template `skip_char`. They have a specific signature which qualifies them as being *manipulators*. When "reading into" a manipulator, the corresponding function is called with the stream they are "read" from. That is, for example `std::cin >> comma` results in a call `comma(std::cin)` which is actually a call to `skip_char<','>(std::cin)`. However, I guess for this assignment the full-blown approach is a bit of overkill.

Comment: damn,Yes I need to make it read in the form a+bi,I understand how the syntax works better cuz of that but I still get errors(i will cover them in the updated question) from just those 2 friend functions that aren't there otherwise when I comment them out,I'm gonna post an updated version of this question since I'm assuming this isn't the correct place since I can't post code in a comment :p