# Predefine >> operator in c++ to skip '(' and ')'

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cin

How to predefine the operator `>>` outside of a class so that I can do it like this:

```
Num number(0,0);
cin >> number; // input is "(1,2)"
```

and I want to use a `set_num1(num1)` function on 1 and `set_num2(num2)` on 2.
So at the end number should be `number(1,2)`. The operator should skip the (,) and just get the number values when reading,no need for any verification.

Comment: You could use [`std::scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) for this, e.g. `std::scanf("(%d,%d)", &num1, &num2);` or you could use [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex)

Comment: But I want to implement it as the >> operator.

Comment: Take a look on this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [overloading Extraction and Insertion << >> operator c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220469/overloading-extraction-and-insertion-operator-c)

Comment: In the standard header `<complex>` there is an operator that can read complex numbers, optionally in the format `(1,2)`. Could give you some inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore the `'('`, `','`, `')'` characters when reading your `Num` class:

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Num& num) {       
   cin.get(); // ignore '('
   int n{0};
   cin >> n;
   num.set_num1(n);       
   cin.get(); // ignore ','
   cin >> n;
   num.set_num2(n);
   cin.get(); // ignore ')'
   return is;
}
```

Note that this code does no validation of the input, whatsoever.